# I want to buy ***.uk domain in GoDaddy with my Indian address is that possible?

Tags: domains, dns, domain-registration, godaddy, domain-registrar

I want to buy `***.uk` domain in GoDaddy with my Indian address because I'm not living in UK,

When I try to register a domain an error message shows that,

> Error: To register a .UK domain name, your administrative contact country must be part of the UK Territories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a requirement for all `.uk` second level domains (SLD). From [Nominet Rules](http://www.nominet.uk/uk-domain-names/registering-uk-domain/choosing-domain-name/rules):

> Where a registrant address is not within the United Kingdom, **a UK address for service must also be supplied**.

That's your "administrative contact".

I don't believe this was a requirement for third level domains (eg. `.co.uk`).

Comment: What happen when i try to give a fake UK "administrative contact".

Comment: I don't know. But in order to give a "fake" UK address, you're likely going to have to give someone else's UK address - as "valid" UK addresses can usually be confirmed, given an up to date postal database. It's possible that Nominet actually send a validating letter in the post to this address (I'm just speculating). This is something they used to do for all UK domains, with login credentials to be able to administer the domain at Nominet - although they no longer seem to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You do need a local valid address in the United Kingdom in order to register for a domain. There are certain domain registrars that offer "Trustee Services"

Here's what I found:

**What are the registration requirements for .UK domains?**

**.UK:**

> All second-level .UK domains (e.g. .CO.UK, .ORG.UK etc) registered
>   prior to June 10, 2014 have priority and the rights to register the
>   same .UK domain name until June 10, 2019. This is valid as long as the
>   original domain remains active. Any 2nd level domains that were
>   registered after June 10, 2014, does not have priority over the same
>   .UK domain, and therefore the .UK domain name is available to the
>   general public.  If another person holds the rights to the
>   registration of the .UK domain you want to register, you will not be
>   able to register that particular .UK domain until after June 10, 2019.
>   If the requested .UK domain is not registered as another United
>   Kingdom extension, it is available to the general public.   You can
>   check here to see if anyone holds the rights to the registration of
>   your new .UK domain. A local address in the United Kingdom is
>   required. If you do not meet this requirement, you can register the
>   domain using the registrar's local address at an additional fee (Trustee Service).

**.CO.UK, .ORG.UK:**

> - There are no requirements.

**.ME.UK:**

> Registrant must be a British natural person.

**.NET.UK:**

> The registrant is required to be a British Internet Service Provider
>   and be listed as a Local Internet Registry. The registered domain name
>   must be the same as or a similar variant of the applicant's name.

It's very important that you don't give a fake address because once they find out, they'll take away the domain registration from you. This is because ICANN requires that every information is legit, from contact number to address. If you use a Trustee Service, the registrar uses their local contacts in a specific country to purchase the domain name for you legally using their own business/residential address or whatever else is needed to complete the registration.